# Speaker turns into default communication device when plugged into front audio panel

Tags: windows-8.1, usb, audio, windows-10, speakers

After installing windows 10 I encountered a problem with my audio.

- In windows 8.1, my speaker when plugged into either rear or front audio jack, would be registered as "default device"
- I in windows 10, when I plug my speaker into the front jack it is registered as "default communication device".
- However, when I plug it in the rear jack it registers as "default device".

This is a problem as my rear jack is broken and I have been using the front jack.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

This is after I installed windows 10, my speaker is set as default communication device:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are plugging your into the microphone jack rather than the audio jack. Attempt plugging your speakers into the other port on the front.

If this is not the case, or it is registered as a microphone no matter which port you plug it in to, it sounds like that would be a driver error. In that case, I would recommend downloading the newest audio drivers form your computer manufacturer's website and seeing if the problem persists.

Comment: I've done what you said and it's still there. And also, I can play the sound if the Digital Output (S/PDIF) is disabled but only with some apps like skype and chrome.